# WebDriver isDisplayed() returns true even if the element is hidden

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

The element I am looking for is as below

[image: HTML body of the element]

I want to call `isDisplayed()` on the highlighted `span` web element, and as it is hidden it should return exception. But it is returning `true` and continuing to the next statement.

Comment: You need to share HTML of this element instead of screenshot as well and also share your Java code which have you tried to verify existence of the element..

Comment: Many things can go wrong here: method is called on wrong element/ method itself!

Comment: The element: 
<span id="registration_layout:regCenterLayoutForm:infoMsgText1" class="" style="background-color: transparent;">Customer already exist in the system.Do you wish to navigate to 360 screen ?</span>

my code is :
try {
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='registration_layout:regCenterLayoutForm:infoMsgText1']")).isDisplayed();

return false;
} catch (Exception msg) {

   return true;
}

Comment: In above code I want to catch the exception in the catch block and make it returns true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question lacks a lot of information.

1. maybe you are looking for some of these: 
   `ispresent()`
   `isvisible()`
   `textpresent()`
   `isDisplayable()`
2. don't know how your code looks but it should be 
   `boolean visible=driver.findElement(By.id("yourverylongid")).isDisplayed();`
   or using xpath

But I am not sure if it will work because I didn't use is Displayed()